# How to get the expression used in an Assign activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

In the line below, "ThenActivity" is an Assign activity nested inside the Then part of an If activity. Im trying to get at the expression, but this snippet isnt working.

((Assign)ThenActivity).To.Expression.ToString();

This returns "1.13: CSharpReference"

When it should read R = 44.5M, which is the expression text, how do I get at it?

Comment: Debug, set a breakpoint, examine the object graph in the quickwatch window?

Comment: Yes, that is what let me find out where it was.  Its the ExpressionText property that is what I actually need.  I just needed to go a bit deeper in the hierarchy.  For example, instead of the above statement, to get the ExpressionText, Im using something like this   ((Assign)ThenActivity).Value.Expression.Result.Expression.ToString()

Comment: Awesome.  Drop an answer below and you can close out your question (that's how we do things around here).

Comment: ok, so instead of the original snippet I posted in the original post, the statement now looks like this  ((CSharpValue<decimal>)(((Assign)ThenActivity).Value.Expression)).ExpressionText  Note, that Im getting the Value component of ThenActivity which is the "Then" part of the If/Then activity im concerned with.  Once you have the assignment activity, you need the expression and the cast that as a CSharpValue (or you can use VisualBasicValue) - then you can get at the ExpressionText...which holds the actual text of the assignment.

Comment: No, I didn't mean in a new comment.... I meant add an answer to your question.  For more info, see [meta].  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The statement should read something like this
((CSharpValue)(((Assign)ThenActivity).Value.Expression)).ExpressionText
Note: You need to get the assignment, then its expression, cast that as a CSharpValue, then finally you can get the ExpressionText.